# AcroPDF in Delphi - How do I scroll?

Tags: delphi, pdf

I'm currently adding a PDF viewer in a Delphi program using TAcroPDF. My problem is, the touch screens that need to show the PDF are rather small, so I wanted to add bigger buttons for scrolling.

I thought I could use the function ScrollBy(DeltaX, DeltaY), but the function scrolls the component within it's container in stead of scrolling the document itself.

Is there some way to scroll the PDF document?

Comment: Have you tried posting keyboard messages? WM_KEYDOWN or WM_KEYPRESS or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

If you are up for rolling your own viewer, take a look at [the QuickPDF Library](http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/).  They have a RenderPageToStream function that will create a reliable image of your document in one of several different formats including BMP, JPG and TIFF among others.  It's a decent solution and I have used it for printing fairly faithful versions of filled-in scanable government forms and have received no complaints from the government agencies where I have submitted them.

Answer (score 0):

PDF browser controls are available through the `AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF` interface (TAcroPDF is just a pdf.ocx Wrapper), which provides, amongst others, the method `SetViewScroll`. This could be the way to go.

Unfortunately, the [official documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.167.html) really sucks (for instance, the page for `SetViewScroll` actually describes `SetViewRect`... wtf?), you will have to do some testing...

Other methods that could be interesting for you are:

- `GotoFirstPage`
- `GotoLastPage`
- `GotoNextPage`
- `GotoPreviousPage`
- `SetCurrentPage`
- `SetView`
- `SetViewRect`

Answer (score 0):

there is another version of official documentation (Intercommunication Communication API reference) in PDF format [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf). It points out the following convenient method for scrolling and zooming at the same time:

> **SetZoomScroll**
>
> Sets the magnification according to the specified value, and scrolls
>   the page view both horizontally and vertically according to the
>   specified amounts.
>
> **Syntax** void setZoomScroll(FLOAT percent, FLOAT left, FLOAT top);

I tried it in .NET 3.5 with C# and VS2010 Express and it works quite faithfully.

Comment: um maybe i misunderstood the initial question - was it about zooming in the Adobe Acrobat viewer control UI? this is different, alright.